# Hide NA values in .Rmd output

Tags: r, r-markdown, rendering

I build a shiny App that lets the user download a pdf report using r markdown.

The user can select an ID and variables (such as Dates...) from a data frame corresponding to this ID are printed in the .Rmd document.

The code inside the .Rmd looks like this:

```
Date of birth: `r Datebirth()`
```

Let's say that no date of birth has been filled into the data frame. The output on the pdf document looks like this:

- Date of birth: NA

When no Date of birth is filled into the dataframe I want that neither "Date of birth" nor "NA" are printed.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write another function that outputs the whole line:

```
DOBline <- function() {
  DOB <- Datebirth()
  if (is.na(DOB)) ""
  else paste("* Date of birth: ", DOB, "\n")
}
```

and then use that in the RMD document.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this "one-line" solution:

```
`r ifelse(is.na(Datebirth()), "", paste("Date of birth":, Datebirth()))`
```

This works in a "normal" Rmd file with a "normal variable", but I don't know if it works with a dynamic shiny variable.

Comment: This would probably work, but it's bad practice to use `ifelse` for control flow.  It  would be better to use `if (is.na(Datebirth()) "" else paste("Date of birth":, Datebirth())`.